# How to use socket.io to communicate with another server when the actual page is being served by a localhost server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm serving my page through localhost (XAMPP, Apache), and on my friend's physical server I run a node.js server that is used for communication with the page (a game).

This is the node.js server code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(1235);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    socket.on("start", function (data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

It runs without any errors, but I don't know how to include the socket.io code into my webpage! How do I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Include a script tag in your page:

```
<script src="http://[YOUR IP]:1235/socket.io/socket.io.js">
```

And it will be served by your node.js server.

Apart from that, you can just follow the examples on [socket.io](http://socket.io/), e.g.:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://[YOUR IP]:1235");

socket.emit("start", "LET'S GO!");
```

Answer (score 1):

2 Options.  Per the documentation, you can do a JavaScript src pointing at your node server:

```
<script src="http://url.to.node.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Or you can include it manually, grabbing it from the Git repo at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/master/dist/socket.io.js