# socket.io and servers

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nginx, socket.io

Is it possible to have socket.io **NOT** be the webserver?

I want to use an external webserver, and for that to work I need /socket.io/socket.io.js.

Is there an alternative to copying<sup>[1]</sup> that, because I don't want to use any crazy proxying, etc. This should be plug and play, so I can grab the file, and move it to another server and have it work there (kind-of like what Websockets is supposed to be like).

[1] = I can sniff the file and make a copy, but this seems hacky and dirty. I want something clean and elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a duplicate of [How to use socket.io to communicate with another server when the actual page is being served by a localhost server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434933/how-to-use-socket-io-to-communicate-with-another-server-when-the-actual-page-is?rq=1)

You need to have `<script src="http://my.url:port/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` to make it work.

Thanks to [Linus G. Theil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295262/linus-g-thiel) for the answer.